# Lesson 5 not working locally

Tags: webgl

I am completely new to WebGL, and have been going through the examples at http://learningwebgl.com/blog/ .  I copied the code in the lessons to a folder on my computer and got lessons 1 through 4 to work locally with Google Chrome, after downloading the JavaScript files glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js and webgl-utils.js.  However, I am unable to get lessons 5 and 6 to work.  In the case of lesson 5, I downloaded the file nehe.gif to the same folder with the HTML and JavaScript code, but it does not work.  All I get is a black square instead of a spinning cube with text.

In the function initTexture() I added the line of code:

```
document.write("<img src='nehe.gif' />");
```

to check that the image containing the text is read, which it is, as it is displayed on the screen, but when this line is commented out, I get back to a black square.

The only changes I have made to the HTML code is to put `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the first line, and remove the two links and the 
 tag in the body of the HTML code.

Lessons 1 through 4 work correctly with Google Chrome, but not with Internet Explorer or Firefox on my Windows computer, but I think that is beside the point, as lesson 5 does not work at all.

I would be most grateful if someone could kindly give me some advice as to how to get lesson 5 to work.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome by default won't allow you to download texture images directly from the local filesystem.

See:

```
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70088
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=57653
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31068
```

Some work-arounds:

```
a) Call chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files in the command-line.
b) Run a webserver locally to supply the textures for Chrome.
c) Use Firefox for examples with textures stored on the local filesystem.
```